# Excel formula on array list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel-formula

In JavaScript, I have 2 objects like below

```
 /* define formula for each cell */
 var formula = { a: '', b: '', c: '=a+b', d: '=c/50*100' };
 var dataRows = [{ a: 100, b: 50, c: '', d: '' }, { a: 101, b: 51, c: '', d: '' }];
```

I need to display dataRows in loop but for "c" and "d" values should be calculate based on formula.

Any help would be appreciable. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use javascript `eval()` method to calculate from formula.

```js
var formula = { a: '', b: '', c: '=a+b', d: '=c/50*100' };
var dataRows = [{ a: 100, b: 50, c: '', d: '' }, { a: 101, b: 51, c: '', d: '' }];

var dataRows = dataRows.map(function(d){
   var a = d.a;
   var b = d.b;
   var c = eval(formula.c.replace('=',''));
   d.d = eval(formula.d.replace('=',''));
   d.c = c;
   return d;
})

console.log(dataRows);
```

- Make sure that you remove '=' character from the formula string.
- **c** value is stored in a separate variable c, so that it can be used by fromula.d

Answer (score 0):

Use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive:

Here is a quick example with your data using a table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in dataRows">
 <th>A: {{ data.a }}</td>
 <td>B: {{ data.b }}</td>
 <td>C: {{ data.a + data.b }}</td>
 <td>D: {{ data.c / (50*100) }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It's not what I asked.. I need to calculate value from a formula.

Comment: I don't get your point, do you want to, let's say, generate all numbers where A is between 100 and 200? @KartikGoyal

Answer (score 0):

Try this lib
https://github.com/fabiooshiro/xlsx-calc 
the data structure follows https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs

```
let sheet = { A1: { v: 3 }, A2: { f: "A1^3" } };
```